# should geofence be a synonym for geofencing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241913/geoserver-geofence-trigger-authentication) today about the GeoServer add on [GeoFence](https://github.com/geoserver/geofence) that was tagged with [`geofencing`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geofencing) which is not what it is about at all. Looking at the tag at least three of the ten most recent questions are about GeoServer security instead of GPS based geofencing (based just on a scan of the titles).

It seems to me that `geofence` should not be a synonym of `geofencing`.

Comment: As a general remark, GeoFence is poorly named IMO. A [tag:geoserver-geofence] tag only removes some of the ambiguity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assumed that geofencing had a common meaning throughout GIS products, open source and commercial, and had no idea that:

> GeoFence is an advanced authentication/authorization engine for GeoServer

To avoid ambiguity I think we should coin a [geoserver-geofence](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoserver-geofence) tag for those questions that are about this form of GeoServer authentication rather than [geofencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence).